# clang libc++ error: overload resolution selected implicitly-deleted copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, std, libc++

I can't get a C++11 project using clang 3.1 to compile. The command to the compiler is this:

```
clang++-mp-3.1 -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -g -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include/mongo -o world.o world.cpp
```

And the error I get, since I included the "-stdlib=libc++" directive, is this:

```
In file included from world.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1952:10: error: overload resolution selected implicitly-deleted copy assignment operator
    __r_ = _STD::move(__str.__r_);
         ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1942:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign' requested here
        __move_assign(__str, true_type());
        ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1961:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign' requested here
    __move_assign(__str, integral_constant<bool,
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:200:24: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=' requested here
struct _LIBCPP_VISIBLE pair
                       ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1941:5: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because '__compressed_pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>
      >::__rep, std::__1::allocator<char> >' has a user-declared move constructor
    __compressed_pair(__compressed_pair&& __p)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Can anyone advise me on how I can get this to work?

The file I'm trying to compile doesn't even have to include any C++11 code for this error to occur, the "-stdlib=libc++" directive alone is enough to make it break.

Thanks for any & all assistance,
   Doug.

UPDATE:
Hi -- the code is pretty basic, but in making it as basic as possible, I came across this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in world.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in world.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in world.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in world.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in world.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To get this error, I stripped my code back to this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  std::cout << "Hi.\n";
}
```

Which makes this look like something pretty fundamentally wrong.

I don't get this error when I take out the "-stdlib=libc++" directive to the compiler.

Comment: Hi -- I added it in to the post, but I'm pretty sure that the code isn't the issue. It might be that my Clang is borked, although I installed it with macports.

Comment: Are you running Mac OSX Lion?

Comment: Yes, I am, with Clang 3.1 installed with macports.

Comment: how did you compile libc++, using gcc or clang itself?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider installing clang from llvm itself. This can be found [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html). I am not 100% sure but perhaps macports or similar has compiled your version against a different  gcc than you have installed. The llvm downloads are compiled against the gcc that in installed  and should prove ABI compatible.

You can also upgrade the libc++.dynlib if you follow the instructions in llvm, but be aware a great many progs in MAC depend on this so you must make a copy of the existing lib (just in case). If you want bleeding edge you may need to dive into these changes. I have done this on a mac and it was perfectly fine and can compile c++11 code just fine.

To build libc++ see [here](http://libcxx.llvm.org/)

Comment: Hi -- cheers for that -- I've compiled the latest llvm (3.1) with clang 3.1, using GCC 4.7
Unfortunately, trying to then compile with the clang compiled from that gives me the exact same error as above.

Comment: Did you rebuild libc++? also you can perhaps try compiling with clang itself. After you have compiled and installed clang when you run clan --version it should look similar to clang version 3.2 (trunk 160613). I really think you should build the latest libc++ though. In my case I used the binaries from the link above (i.e. I did not compile llvm) and it was fine. I have also recompiled libc++ for some aspects that were missing.

Comment: No, I haven't changed libc++, yet, but I guess that'll be the next step.
I'll hopefully get to that after work tonight & report back how I get on.
& thanks again for your help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: Agh, I tried rebuilding libc++ on my lunch hour, installed it, and got exactly the same error.
I guess it must be something else that's at issue.
Thanks very much for your advice, though.

Comment: No problem. It's strange we installed a new libc++ and clang on 2 more mac's in house today (Lion). There is a helper required for snow leopard though. Good luck though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution).

In short, when this happens it is because one of the possible overloads was declared as forbidden, hence the overload resolution fails. To get around it you should explicitly cast to make that forbidden overload not be one of the resolutions for the call.

See the accepted answer to the linked question for a very detailed and well written explanation.