# ternary operator of different types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The following piece of code behaves differently under g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.7.0.  Which one is correct?  What part in standard is related to this?  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
  Base() = default;
  Base(const Base&) = default;
  Base(Base&&) = delete;
};

struct Derived : Base {
};

int main() {
  const Base& b = true ? Derived() : Base();
}
```

g++ accepts it and clang++ gives an error `incompatible operand types ('Derived' and 'Base')`.  See below for details.

```
[hidden]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC) 
[hidden]$ g++ -std=c++11 b.cpp 
[hidden]$ clang++ -v
clang version 3.7.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 6bbdbba8ec8a7730c68fee94363547dc2dc65b10)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
[hidden]$ clang++ -std=c++11 b.cpp 
b.cpp:14:24: error: incompatible operand types ('Derived' and 'Base')
  const Base& b = true ? Derived() : Base();
                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Clang might be expecting you to use an explicit cast

Comment: @dyp: Chris didn't say that copy-initialization implies using a copy constructor, which is false: if there is a move constructor, the copy constructor may not be needed.  He said since there is a copy constructor, copy-initialization should succeed, which is true, either there is a usable move constructor, or there isn't and the copy constructor gets used.

Comment: @BenVoigt, It's OK, I really was not paying enough attention when it said copy-initialization. Looking further, it should come down to which constructor is picked by overload resolution for `Base b = Derived();`

Comment: @BenVoigt Now I'm a bit confused: OP's `Base` class has an *explicitly deleted* move ctor. Hence, copy-init from an rvalue should fail, right?

Comment: @dyp, I think that's correct.

Comment: @dyp: Hmm, I suppose you wouldn't do that to disable an auto-generated move constructor, since a move constructor wouldn't be auto-generated in this circumstance.  So it must be to prohibit cases where overload selection would choose the move constructor.  But then the error message still seems totally wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt I normally wouldn't explicitly delete a move ctor. But it's in the OP's code, and I think it leads to a reasonable explanation as to why clang++ rejects it. -- Agreed, error message is bad/misleading/not helpful.

Comment: @dyp, Perhaps it's worth letting the Clang guys know about the abnormal error message in this case? It is rather contrived, I'll admit.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' great discussion here.  I am more interested in whether standard thinks it is ill-formed or not, than why clang is wrong (is it wrong?).  IMHO, for every program, standard should be clear whether it is ill-formed or not; otherwise, the standard is broken and should be fixed.   Also, I am a little confused, why copy or move is involved here? I was thinking it should be just the same as `const Base& b = Derived();`, so maybe I missed something.  Does `true ? Derived() : Base()` construct a `Derived` object and then truncate it to `Base`?

Comment: @icando, The conditional operator requires both operands to be the same type minus a couple of exceptions (hence my quoted text beginning with "Otherwise"). Since `Base()` and `Derived()` are not the same type, `Derived()` will be converted to a `Base` temporary object to be used as the operand instead. `true ? Derived() : Base()` still has the same rules apply, so the result is still a `Base`, despite `Derived()` being the chosen operand. The thing is that by the time it's chosen, it's not a `Derived`, it's already a `Base`.

Comment: @chris, why doesn't it convert to `const Base&` but `Base`?

Comment: @icando, You can't bind temporaries to non-const lvalue references. The result of the conditional operator is an lvalue only if both operands (with any new type after the quoted process) are lvalues of the same type.

Comment: @chris, can you add that to your answer?  Where in the standard says `:?` has lvalue only if both operands are lvalues of the same type?

Comment: @icando, I don't find it relevant to the question, so it's a bit noisy in the answer, but it's right after the quoted text, in /4: *If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result
is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if
both are bit-fields*

Comment: Tangential question: is there any way to do what OP was trying to do? (i.e. have a reference bind directly to either a `Base()` or `Derived()` depending on the condition, and extend the temporary's lifetime?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Good question. Would casting both operands to `const Base &` work? I have a slight feeling the lifetime of the temporary might not be extended past that line in that case.

Comment: @chris yeah, lifetime is only extended on direct binding (i.e. binding to a prvalue) , and binding a reference to a reference doesn't count because that is binding to an lvalue (or xvalue in the case of rvalue references)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I don't think it is possible even in principle to have the lifetime of the temporary extended here since the destruction of the temporary would occur at the end of the scope and it would have to know which destructor to call (~Base or ~Derived) based on a previous decision, but that information is lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have N3936 handy, but N3797 §5.12 [expr.cond]/3 contains this (emphasis mine):

> Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and
>   either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or if both are glvalues
>   of the same value category and the same type except for
>   cv-qualification, an attempt is made to convert each of those operands
>   to the type of the other. The process for determining whether an
>   operand expression E1 of type T1 can be converted to match an operand
>   expression E2 of type T2 is defined as follows:
>
> - If E2 is an lvalue: [removed]
> - If E2 is an xvalue: [removed]
> - If E2 is a prvalue or if neither of the conversions
>     above can be done and at least one of the operands has (possibly
>     cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - if **E1 and E2 have class type**, and the
>       underlying class types are the same or **one is a base class of the
>       other**:
>       E1 can be converted to match E2 if the class of T2 is the same
>       type as, **or a base class of**, the class of T1, and the cv-qualification
>       of T2 is the same cv-qualification as, or a greater cv-qualification
>       than, the cv-qualification of T1. If the conversion is applied, E1 is
>       changed to a prvalue of type T2 by **copy-initializing** a temporary of
>       type T2 from E1 and using that temporary as the converted operand.
>
> Using this process, it is determined whether the **second operand can be 
>   converted to match the third operand**, and whether the third operand
>   can be converted to match the second operand. If both can be
>   converted, or one can be converted but the conversion is ambiguous,
>   the program is ill-formed. If neither can be converted, the operands
>   are left unchanged and further checking is performed as described
>   below. **If exactly one conversion is possible, that conversion is
>   applied to the chosen operand and the converted operand is used in
>   place of the original operand for the remainder of this section.**

Now to copy-initialize the final `Base` operand from `Derived()`, we can look at §13.3.1.3  [over.match.ctor]:

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized (8.5), or
>   **copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class
>   type** (8.5), overload resolution **selects the constructor**. For
>   direct-initialization, the candidate functions are all the
>   constructors of the class of the object being initialized. **For
>   copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the converting
>   constructors (12.3.1) of that class**. The argument list is the
>   expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.

Converting constructors are defined as follows in §12.3.1 [class.conv.ctor]:

> A constructor declared without the function-specifier explicit
>   specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters to the type of
>   its class. Such a constructor is called a converting constructor.

Now, if you'll believe me (for the sake of not having to quote more than I have of 13.3) that a prvalue `Derived()` will cause overload resolution to choose the move constructor (taking `Base&&`), [despite being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution), this causes the error from Clang.

In conclusion, Clang is correct in issuing an error. As using a deleted function requires a diagnostic, this is a bug in GCC.

Comment: Clang is indeed trying to move it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6542febd5d884ecc

Comment: I am confused, why move constructor is involved here?  What does it try to move, and where does it try to move to?

Comment: @dyp, That would be my bad. Let me go back and look.

Comment: @chris, it still not clear from your answer - maybe it is implied by your answer but I'd rather something more explicit - whether the program is ill-formed or not and which one of gcc and clang is correct.

Comment: The text seems to be saying that `Derived()` is **sliced** to make a new `Base()` which is then bound to the reference if that item is selected. This is a surprising behaviour.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not sure if it is that surprising in general. If the expression has to yield a prvalue, and the selected operand is an glvalue, you'd have to make a copy (potentially causing slicing in the process). In this case, of course, the operand is a prvalue, but "slice only for glvalues" is probably equally surprising.