# integral_constants in ternary operator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

MSVC and clang/gcc disagree on whether two different integral constants can be used in a ternary operator (and as a consequence whether they have a `common_type`):

```
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    return false
        ? std::integral_constant<int, 1>() 
        : std::integral_constant<int, 2>();
}
```

The above snippet compiles fine in clang and gcc, but not in MSVC. What is the correct behavior according to the standard? And if it's clang/gcc behavior then what are the conversion sequences used to deduce the common type of these two distinct types?

Comment: Well, they are both implicitly convertible to `int`, and I think that's their common type.

Comment: They are, but I'm trying to decide if the compiler is allowed to seek that match.  That's the unclear part.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381171/ternary-operator-of-different-types)?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well, explicit cast makes it very simple as integral_constants are implicitly convertible to their underlying type. Same for the question you linked - derived to base conversion could be a part of a conversion sequence to one of the operands. But I don't see anything in cppreference showing that the compiler would search for _some_ type both operands are convertible to - it should be one or the other operand's type that's the result. In the case of ``integral_constant`` the result type is not either of the operands which is why it's confusing why it compiles on gcc/clang

Comment: @Rostislav The accepted answer of the linked question cites the parts of the standard listing the allowed conversions which I think may be relevant.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Yeah, I'm interpreting that chunk as saying both clang and gcc are wrong...which surprises me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tldr; The code is well-formed. The conditional expression will have type `int` and value `2`. This is an MSVC bug.

---

From [expr.cond]:

> Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or [...], an attempt is made to form an implicit conversion sequence (13.3.3.1) from each of those operands to the type of the other. [...] Attempts are made to form an implicit conversion sequence from an operand expression `E1` of type `T1` to a target type related to the type `T2` of the operand expression `E2` as follows: [...]
>   — If E2 is an lvalue, [...]
>   — If E2 is an xvalue, [...]
>   — If E2 is a prvalue or if neither of the conversion sequences above can be formed and at least one of the
>   operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>         — if T1 and T2 are the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification), or one is a base class of the other,
>   and T2 is at least as cv-qualified as T1, the target type is T2,
>         — otherwise, the target type is the type that E2 would have after applying the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1),
>   array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions.

So we're trying to form an implicit conversion sequence from type `std::integral_constant<int, 1>` to type `std::integral_constant<int, 2>`. That's not viable. Nor is the implicit conversion sequence in the reverse direction viable either. These types are simply not interconvertible.

So we continue:

> If no conversion
>   sequence can be formed, the operands are left unchanged and further checking is performed as described
>   below. [...]
>
> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, [...]
>
> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either
>   has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be
>   applied to the operands (13.3.1.2, 13.6). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed.

Ok, what overload resolution can we perform? From [over.match.oper]:

> If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be declared that implements this operator or **a user-defined conversion can be necessary** to convert the operand to
>   a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator.

Where the builtins are specified in [over.built] as:

> For every pair of promoted arithmetic types L and R, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> LR operator?:(bool, L , R );
> ```
>
> where LR is the result of the usual arithmetic conversions between types L and R.

One of those builtins would be `int operator?:(bool, int, int)`. Since `std::integral_constant<int, V>` does have an `operator int()`, this is a viable conversion for both arguments.

We continue in [expr.cond]:

> Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this section.
>
> Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed
>   on the second and third operands. After those conversions, one of the following shall hold:
>   — The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type and the result object is initialized using the selected operand.

At this point, the second and third operands *do* have the same type: `int`. So the result object is initialized as an `int`, and the expression is well-formed.

Answer (score 6):

The relevant paragraph from [expr.cond] is [6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#6):

> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands
>   do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified)
>   class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions
>   (if any) to be applied to the operands (13.3.1.2, 13.6). If the
>   overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the
>   conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands
>   are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this
>   section.

`integral_constant<int>` has a conversion operator to `int`, so this can work.
Following through to [13.3.1.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper), we see that by [paragraph 3.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.3), all builtin `?:` operators taking integer and floating point arguments are candidates.

Now overload resolution is performed for all these, given our three arguments. As per [[over.ics.rank]/3.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#over.ics.rank-3.3), we tie-break by comparing the standard conversion sequences from `int` (the return type of `integral_constant<int>`'s conversion operator) to the builtin operators' parameter types.

However, a look at [table 13](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.scs#tab:over.conversions) is enough; conversions to the floating point types have Conversion rank, and since `int` is a promoted type, converting to any integral type **but `int`** (which is an identity conversion) is an integral conversion with Conversion rank. Hence the best viable candidate is, unambiguously, `operator?:(bool, int, int)`. That is, MSVC is wrong.