# Incompatible operands to ternary op

Tags: c++, c++11

I stumbled upon a strange problem when writing lambda expressions. Here's the code:

```
#if 1 /* exhibit A */
        const auto giveup = this->__randomGiveUp();
        auto evtFunc = [this, giveup]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
          if (giveup) {
            this->__releaseLock();
          }
        };
#endif
#if 0 /* exhibit B */
        auto evtFunc = this->__randomGiveUp() ? (std::function<void()>)[this]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
          this->__releaseLock();
        } : [this]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
        };
#endif
#if 0 /* exhibit C */
        auto evtFunc = this->__randomGiveUp() ? [this]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
          this->__releaseLock();
        } : [this]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
        };
#endif
#if 0 /* exhibit D */
        std::function<void()> evtFunc = this->__randomGiveUp() ? [this]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
          this->__releaseLock();
        } : [this]() {
          this->__acquireLock();
        };
#endif

        this->__eventCtx.addEvent(this->__tickStart + this->__randomAcquireDelay(), evtFunc);
```

My original code that I thought would work was **C**. They all basically do the same thing. GCC and Clang(which Atom's linter uses) produces:

- What works: A, B
- What doesn't: C, D

Saying the operands are not the same type. This is strange to me. My assumption was that every lambda expression is given a unique type, but that doesn't explain the exhibit B, which works. And why doesn't D work while B does? Is it just that the compiler making wild guesses when determining lambda types?

So, my question is:

- Why B work???
- Are lambda expressions each have their own unique type and need to be cast(then again, how come B works??)?
- Is this a bug?

For clarification, the return type of `this->__randomGiveUp()` is bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are lambda expressions each have their own unique type and need to be cast(then again, how come B works??)?

Yes, they are. Result of lambda expression is a function object of unnamed type. You have to wrap it up into `std::function` or some similar template that can be initialized from lambda, lest lambda expression is capture-less (empty capture list). The latter can be cast to a function pointer, thus  can be used with ternary (Microsoft compiler here may think otherwise because it have several intermediate pointer to function types, different in calling conventions):

```
double (*square)(double)  = [](double a)->double { return a*a; };

auto foo = (square) ? [](double a)->double { return a*a; } :
            [](double a)->double { return a*a*a; };
```

B variant seem to do the cast of second operand implicitly (or , rather, create a `std::function` object using appropriate constructor) by mechanics of ternary operator. You can  check here: [Ternary operator of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381171/ternary-operator-of-different-types?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Yeah, ternary op became a big of a mess when C++ is introduced to this world. What a brain teaser it is when different types are involved. Might as well just not use it.

Comment: @Ashethehuman it's a model of actual CPU instruction (conditional copy)..of course that may occur only with same (size operands) types, because it's an assignment

Answer (score 2):

Each lambda function has its own distinct type. That is the reason that C and D do not work: There is no conversion between the second and third operands. C++ does not attempt to convert to some unrelated type such as `std::function` if neither operand is already of that type.

And that explains why B works: the second operator is of type `std::function<>` the lambda function type of the third operand can be converted to the type of the second operand via the `std::function` constructor.

Comment: it's more complex that just conversion\cast in case of ternary operator, it able to do copy initialization of temporary to match second operand to first. And don't forget lambdas without capture list, ternary would work with them.