# C++: Using auto to declare classes as variables inside functions

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, c++17

I'm trying to use auto for all local variables inside my functions.

Take the following code:

```
class obj 
{
  public:
  obj() {};
  obj( obj&& o ) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  obj test0;
  auto test1 = obj();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling the code:

```
$ g++ --std=c++1z main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13:20: error: use of deleted function ‘obj::obj(obj&&)’
   auto test1 = obj();
```

Notice that defining test0 is completely okay, but attempting to do the exact same type of declaration of test1 is a compiler error.  Clearly is should be a compiler error, but in this case, does it mean *obj* can't be defined with auto?  I'm running into this problem with QT objects I don't have control over.

Am I suck still using the C++98 format for declaring variables or is there another way to use auto?

Thanks!!!

Comment: With `auto test1 = obj();`, you are using "copy initialization". However, `obj` is neither copy constructible (it has a move constructor declared, preventing the implicit generation of the copy constructor) nor move constructible (it is declared as deleted).

Comment: To prevent such traps in the future, consider using C++'s "Rule of 5"

Comment: Thank you, I understand what is happening and why it doesn't work.  My question was, can auto be used with a class like this?  If so how.

Comment: those two lines are not doing the exact same thing at all. Actually I dont know any circumstances under which a declaration `obj test0;` could fail to compile while I could imagine lots of reasons why `auto test1 = obj();` fails to compile

Comment: obj test0 would fail to compile if obj() constructor was private.

Comment: @LukeDupin oh of course, what a stupid comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is OK in C++17; guaranteed copy elision adjusts the rules so that a move constructor isn't even conceptually called, so it doesn't matter if it's deleted or inaccessible.

Before then, if you love `auto` so much, you can do

```
auto&& test1 = obj();
```

This creates a temporary `obj` object and binds it to the reference `test1`, extending its lifetime to that of the reference. With a few exceptions, the behavior is pretty much identical to what you will get in C++17 with plain `auto`.

Comment: Do rvalue references extend the lifetime of temporaries the same way `const auto &` does?

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yes.

Comment: Oh boy!!! I just tried it and this works.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for actually reading the question instead of explaining why deleted methods can't be called!

Answer (score 3):

In the declaration

```
auto test1 = obj();
```

the compiler tries to move the object on the rhs, as it is a rvalue. It cannot (as the move ctor is marked as deleted). Note that because the move ctor is deleted, then the copy ctor is deleted as well, although the compiler will only try to move (because the move ctor, even though deleted, it is still consider user-defined and [it is selected as a candidate during overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution)). Hence, your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you, I understand exactly what its doing, my question is, can auto still be used to declare the variable test1 in this case?

Comment: The `auto` declaration is fine and has nothing to do with the compilation failure.

Answer (score 3):

The error has nothing to do with the use of `auto` specifically.

```
obj test1 = obj();
```

doesn't compile as well. 
`obj()` is a r-value, that the compiler tries to move but the move constructor is deleted. Deleting the move constructor prevents the compiler of creating a copy constructor as well, so it can't copy it too, hence the error.