# Does delete/default keywords mark the corresponding method as user defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class B{
public:
    //this should all be generated by default but
    //throwing them in here just to be sure
    B() = default;
    B(const B& b) = default;
    B& operator=(const B& b) = default;
    B(B&& b) = default;
    B& operator=(B&& b) = default;
};

class A {
public:
    A(B x) : x_(x) {}
    A(const A& a) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A& a) = delete;
    //move operations should be generated by compiler?
private:
    B x_;
};

int main() {
    A a = A(B());
}
```

I'm expecting this to compile and an `A` to be created using it's move constructor, but instead this fails with the following message:

> error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
>        A a = A(B());
>   note: declared here
>        A(const A& a) = delete;

Of course adding the move operations and marking them with the default keywords eliminates the problem. Should I assume that the move operations were not generated by the compiler, why is that? Does delete keyword mark the methods as user-implemented so no move operations are generated? Why is the copy constructor prefered instead? I'm using gcc to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide implementation of copy constructor/`operator=`, move operations are no longer generated *by default*. If you want them, you need to explicitly tell that you do.

As per cppreference:

> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type
>   (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared move assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared destructors;
>
> then the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit
>   inline public member of its class with the signature `T::T(T&&)`.

Here's a helpful chart for this kind of situation:

[image]
[attribution](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/11/becoming-a-rule-of-zero-hero/)

Comment: But i thought i didn't. I just deleted all copy operations from class A. Is that considered user-implementation?

Comment: @cuvidk deleted functions take part in overload resolution, so yeah, it counts as defined (as deleted) - to the best of my understanding. I'll try to hunt the wording for this

Comment: I consider your answer extremely helpful. The above table clears things up if your caught in the constructor-chaos as I am. I tried to search if keywords as delete/default count as user-defined but couldn't find answers.

Comment: But if deleting the copy operations is considered user-defined implementation and so as a consequence the move operations are deleted, why is replacing `A a = A(B());` with `A a(A(B()));` working?

Comment: @cuvidk try using `a` ;) You've hit Most Vexing Parse. (`a` is a function returning `A` and taking function returning `A` and taking function returning `B` and taking no arguments)

Comment: (if it helps) Here is a video description of a transposed version of the above chart: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk&t=23m20s

Comment: @HowardHinnant thank you, it was illuminating. Am I correct to say that the chart from this answer isn't entirely truthful about move ops when a copy operation is declared? (according to your chart, they're not declared + overload will select copy ops)

Comment: @krzaq:  I think the observable result is the same either way:  overload resolution will select copying (assuming the user doesn't declare move ops).

Answer (score 2):

Saying `= delete` you're not just saying that the code is not present, but that if code tries to call that you should get a compile error.

More specifically `delete`d members are not simply removed from the set of available options: they are searched and if they match you get a compile error. In other words `= delete` is meant for signatures that when match imply a usage problem, not for signature you don't want to match.

For example `delete`d members [do indeed participate in overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14085710/320726).

Providing `= delete` **is exactly like providing an implementation**, with the difference that if the compiler ends up generating code that would call the deleted function then you have a compile error. If you provide a `delete`d copy constructor you still provided a user defined copy constructor.

Another subtle point you should pay attention to is that automatic generation of move constructor/assignment depends for example on the presence of a "user defined copy constructor" and that definition as a strict meaning. Something that is not logically obvious (at least wasn't for me) is that a template matching the signature of a copy constructor is not a copy constructor. In other words in:

```
struct Foo {
    template<typename T>
    Foo(const T& other) { ... }
};
```

the template can match `Foo(const Foo&)` but **is not considered a user-defined copy constructor**  (don't look for a deep reason, it's this way because the standard says so) and therefore you still get implicitly generated move constructors. If the default implementation is not correct this will be a source of serious problems...