# Ambigous call of constructor with gcc 8.2.1

Tags: c++, gcc, unique-ptr, constructor-overloading

This program defines a simple container for an array of `std::unique_ptr<unsigned int>`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <unsigned int dim>
class container {
  template <std::size_t... I>
  container(std::array<unsigned int, dim> Ls, std::index_sequence<I...>) : container(std::get<I>(Ls)...) { }

public:
  const std::array<std::unique_ptr<unsigned int>, dim> data;

  template <typename... UInts, class = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(UInts) == dim) && (std::is_same_v<UInts, unsigned int> && ...)>>
  container(UInts... Ls) : data{ std::make_unique<unsigned int>(Ls)...} { }

  template <typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<dim>>
  container(std::array<unsigned int, dim> Ls) : container(Ls, Indices{}) { }
};

int main()
{
  unsigned int x = 1;
  unsigned int y = 2;

  container<2> a({x,y});

  return 0;
}
```

The compilation with gcc 8.2.1 fails however, with the following error.

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp

test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:25:23: error: call of overloaded ‘container(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
   container<2> a({x,y});
                       ^
test.cpp:17:3: note: candidate: ‘container<dim>::container(std::array<unsigned int, dim>) [with Indices = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0, 1>; unsigned int dim = 2]’
   container(std::array<unsigned int, dim> Ls) : container(Ls, Indices{}) { }
   ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:6:7: note: candidate: ‘container<2>::container(const container<2>&)’ <deleted>
 class container {
       ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:6:7: note: candidate: ‘container<2>::container(container<2>&&)’ <deleted>
make: *** [Makefile:3: test] Error 1
```

Indeed, the copy constructor is deleted because of the presence of the array of `std::unique_ptr` (but still [participates to the overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution)).

Strangely, on gcc 7.3.0 the above code compiles with no errors or warnings.

Also, defining a simplified container, having a copyable array of `unsigned int`, as in the following program, no error occurs with both gcc 8.2.1 and gcc 7.3.0

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <unsigned int dim>
class container_simple {
  template <std::size_t... I>
  container_simple(std::array<unsigned int, dim> Ls, std::index_sequence<I...>) : container_simple(std::get<I>(Ls)...) { }

public:
  const std::array<unsigned int, dim> data;

  template <typename... UInts, class = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(UInts) == dim) && (std::is_same_v<UInts, unsigned int> && ...)>>
  container_simple(UInts... Ls) : data{ Ls...} { }

  template <typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<dim>>
  container_simple(std::array<unsigned int, dim> Ls) : container_simple(Ls, Indices{}) { }
};

int main()
{
  unsigned int x = 1;
  unsigned int y = 2;

  container_simple<2> a({x,y});

  return 0;
}
```

Is it a compiler bug? If not, where is the ambiguity?

Comment: `container<2> a{{x,y}};` also compiles fine of both clang/gcc [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c15dc1e51842cda)

Comment: *"where is the ambiguity?"* `{x,y}` might be `std::array` or `container_simple(UInts... Ls)`. but I don't understand behavior of the different variations.

Comment: Marking explicitly the copy constructor as deleted make gcc compile (but clang complains) [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d0656349be0dd7e)