# Understanding how compiler uses plain {}-list inside initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, list-initialization

Consider the following toy code:

```cpp
class Y
{
public:
    Y(int, int) { cout << "Y ctor\n"; }
};

class X
{
public:
    //X(initializer_list<int>) { cout << "init\n"; }      // 1
    X(Y&&) { cout << "Y&&\n"; }                         // 2
    X(int, int) { cout << "param\n"; }                  // 3
    X(const X&) { cout << "X&\n"; }                     // 4
    X(const Y&) { cout << "Y&\n"; }                     // 5
    X(Y) { cout << "Y\n"; }                             // 6
    X(X&&) { cout << "X&&\n"; }                         // 7
};

void f(const X&) {  }
void f(const Y&) {  }
void f(Y) {  }

int main()
{
    X x({1,2});
    //f({ 1,2 });                                         // 8
}
```

I'm trying to understand how the compiler uses `{1,2}` in `X x({1,2})`. Followings are my understandings:

- Uncomment line `1`

  In such case, I think `X x({1,2})` is an explicit call for `X(initializer_list<int>)`. That is, when compiler sees `{}`-list, I think it will first see it as `std::initializer_list` and a constructor that takes an argument of `initializer_list<T>` will be the better match than all the others.
- Comment out line `6`, `7`

  In such case, I think `{1,2}` is used to construct an object of `Y` which is bound with an rvalue reference (i.e. compiler chooses to call `X(Y&&)`). My guess here is that the compiler treats `{1,2}` as some kind of rvalue when there is no constructor that takes an argument of `initializer_list<T>`, and thus a constructor that takes an rvalue reference is preferred (in this case, `X(Y&&)` is the only constructor of this kind).

  **Update:** I found that the behavior I described in this bullet point is actually a [bug](https://godbolt.org/z/ozad3aTxx) of MSVC. gcc and clang will report ambiguity, not calling `X(Y&&)`
- Comment out line `7`

  Ambiguity arises. Compiler reports that both `X(Y&&)` and `X(Y)` match. I think this is because although `X(Y&&)` is a better match than `X(const Y&)` and `X(const X&)`, it is indistinguishable to `X(Y)`. (I think the logic here is quite twisted)

  Possible [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961890/16500459).
- Comment out line `2`,`7`

  The code compiles and prints `param`. I think this time `X(const X&)` is chosen but I'm not sure why. My guess for this is that, when all the viable matches (`X(const X&)`, `X(const Y&)` and `X(Y)`) are indistinguishable, the compiler chooses `X(const X&)` because `X x({1,2});` is constructing an `X`.

  **Update:** this can also be a MSVC [bug](https://godbolt.org/z/TPbx7r7aE). gcc and clang will report ambiguity, not calling `X(const X&)`
- Comment out line `2`,`7` and uncomment line `8`

  I think this is the case where all the viable matches are indistinguishable and `f` is not a constructor of `X`, hence `f(const X&)` is not treated specially, and ambiguity arises.

May I ask if my understandings are correct? (I highly doubt they are accurate)

---

I find that it is quite tedious to read out what constructor is invoked by things like `X x({1,2});`, so I guess in real code we should try to avoid such shorthand and write code in a more explicit way...

---

On the other hand, if we use the same settings for class `X` and `Y` as above, define and call a function `g` as follows:

```cpp
X g()
{
    return { 1,2 };
}

int main()
{
    g();
}
```

The results always seem to be equivalent as initializing the returned temporary by `X{1,2}` (i.e. call `X(initializer_list<int>)` when it exists, and in all the other cases call `X(int, int)`). May I ask if this is true?

Comment: You should make a lot of the constructors explicit so they do not get used with implicit conversion. Writing `X x{1, 2};` should also cut down on the confusion. Generally the fewer constructors you have the better.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Tell that to [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)!

Answer (score 1):

1. `X x({1,2})` can’t be an “explicit call for” a `std::initializer_list`: a *braced-init-list* has **no type**.  However, there is a rule saying that one is a better match for a specialization of that template than for any other class type.
2. `X(Y&&)` is used because `X(const X&)` isn’t viable.  It would be considered a **second** user-defined conversion even though `{…}`→`Y`→`X` isn’t (because of the two layers of initialization).
3. Yes, `Q` and `Q&&` are often ambiguous like that.  Consider that C++17 prvalues don’t even move to initialize either.
4. Presumably you meant you commented out lines 2 and 6.  In that case, the constructors from (references to) `X` are disqualified as above, and `X(const Y&)` is a worse match because the `const` must be **added** to the non-const list-initialized prvalue.  (All user-defined conversions are otherwise indistinguishable.)
5. `f(Y)` is better than the other two regardless of `X`’s constructors for the same `const` reason.

As for `g`, yes copy-list-initialization is much the same as direct-list-initialization in the absence of **explicit** constructors.  Since it *is* list-initialization, rather than direct initialization from an “argument” that is a *braced-init-list*, it **does** prefer an initializer-list constructor over all others.