# Overwriting entries from a matrix in cpp11

Tags: c++, r, r-lib-cpp11

I have some Rcpp code to fill entries in a matrix, here's a MWE of what it does:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

void invert_tri(NumericMatrix &M, int K) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<K ; ++i) {
        for(int j=i+1 ; j<K ; ++j) {
            M(j, i) = M(i, j);
        }
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix multiply_entries(NumericMatrix M, int factor) {
    int K = M.ncol();

    for(int i=0 ; i<K ; ++i) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<K ; ++j) {
            M(i, j) = M(i, j) * factor;
        }
    }

    invert_tri(M, K);

    return M;
}
```

Then in R I would use it like this:

```
M = matrix(c(1,NA,2,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

multiply_entries(M, 2L)
```

This changes

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]   NA    4
```

into

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    4    8
```

Then, with cpp11 I would sketch the following code

```
#include <cpp11.hpp>
#include <cpp11/doubles.hpp>

using namespace cpp11;

void invert_tri(writable::doubles_matrix<> &M, int K) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<K ; ++i) {
        for(int j=i+1 ; j<K ; ++j) {
            M(j, i) = M(i, j);
        }
    }
}

[[cpp11::register]]
doubles_matrix<> multiply_entries(writable::doubles_matrix<> M, int factor) {
    int K = M.ncol();

    for(int i=0 ; i<K ; ++i) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<K ; ++j) {
            M(i, j) = M(i, j) * factor;
        }
    }

    invert_tri(M, K);

    return M;
}
```

But here doing `M(j, i) += M(i, j)` would fail and with `=` fails because of implicit deletion. Do you have any ideas for an alternative approach to translate the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe not the best approach for large matrices, but this just works

```
void invert_tri(writable::doubles_matrix<> &M, int K) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<K ; ++i) {
        for(int j=i+1 ; j<K ; ++j) {
            M(j, i) += (-1.0 * M(j, i)) + M(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original code fails because the compiler can't resolve which type of assignment to perform in the statement `M(j, i) = M(i ,j)`

**Explanation**:

1. Both the left and right hand side are of type `r_vector<double>::proxy`.
2. The right-hand-side value can be cast to a `double`, for which there is a valid assignment to the left hand side.
3. The copy and move assignment operators for this type (`r_vector<double>proxy>`) are both deleted due to const-qualifiers on members.
4. While you would think that because there is only one non-deleted assignment that there would be no problem - however - [deleted assignment operators are still considered during overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14085710/7050789).

The simplest solution I can think of is to force the compiler into a corner by casting the right hand side to a double, e.g.

```cpp
void invert_tri(writable::doubles_matrix<> &M, int K) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<K ; ++i) {
        for(int j=i+1 ; j<K ; ++j) {
            M(j, i) = (double)M(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```